# How to go back in dialog

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Sometimes I accidentally answer too quickly so it's not the one I want.

Is there a way to take back a response and give another instead?

Comment: ...Reload a save?  That's generally how it has to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. You'll have to reload your latest save. Only thing *remotely* close is reading back your chat log and see whatever your conversation was before.

PS. Is there any RPG where you *can* "undo" chat?

Answer (score 0):

*(played Extended Edition only)*

I don't think you can undo your answer. But what you can do is **scroll up** to see earlier conversation. 
Often, for non vital conversation you can choose the other options after the text from the option you selected is done.

An example of this is when you reach the weaver of time. You will have multiple conversation options. Each option will give you a bunch of text. After that you will still be able to choose all other options.